# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined with two middlewares involved

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have to run test on my ts-node app and i am having this problem when running the test, for context the app has routes that has to pass two middlewares, one of authorization and another of valid request i have this config route

```
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/cars', requiredAuthorization, requiredHeadersValidator, cars);


router.use('/healthcheck', healthcheck());

export default router;
```

and i get this error while running the test:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

   8 | const cars = require('../routes/cars');
   9 |
> 10 | router.use('/cars', requiredAuthorization, requiredHeadersValidator, cars);
     |        ^
  11 | router.use('/healthcheck', healthcheck());
  12 |
  13 | export default router;

  at Function.use (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/web-server/routes/index.ts:10:8)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/web-server/index.ts:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/web-server/middlewares/required-authorization.ts:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/web-server/middlewares/__tests__/required-authorization.test.ts:4:1)
```

i have tried almost every answer here and in other parts but none of them seems to help (in every file of routing there is a export default router line)

**Update**

The middlewares are:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { autho } from '../index';

const requiredAuthorization = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN)
    .json({
      errors: [{
        status: StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN, detail: 'Unauthorized'
      }]
    });
  }

  let idToken;
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  } else {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN)
    .json({
      errors: [{
        status: StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN, detail: 'Unauthorized'
      }]
    });
  }

  try {
    await autho.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    next();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN)
    .json({
      errors: [{
        status: StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN, detail: 'Unauthorized'
      }]
    });
  }

};

export default requiredAuthorization;
```

and:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { ReasonPhrases, StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

const requiredHeadersValidator = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.header('Content-Type') !== 'application/vnd.api+json') {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
      .json({
        errors: [{
          status: StatusCodes.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, detail: ReasonPhrases.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
        }]
      });
  }

  if (req.header('Accept') !== 'application/vnd.api+json') {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
      .json({
        errors: [{
          status: StatusCodes.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, detail: ReasonPhrases.NOT_ACCEPTABLE
        }]
      });
  }

  next();
};

export default requiredHeadersValidator;
```

the imports:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as healthcheck from 'express-healthcheck';
import requiredAuthorization from '../middlewares/required-authorization';
import requiredHeadersValidator from '../middlewares/required-headers-validator';
import cars from './cars';
```

the cars.ts file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { BrandController } from '../controllers/brand-controller';
import { ModelController } from '../controllers/model-controller';
import { VehicleController } from '../controllers/vehicle-controller';

const router = express.Router();

// brands
router.get('/brands', BrandController.findAll);
router.get('/brands/:id', BrandController.findById);
router.get('/brands/:id/models', BrandController.findModelsByBrandId);
router.post('/brands', BrandController.create);
router.patch('/brands/:id', BrandController.updateBrandById);
router.delete('/brands/:id', BrandController.deleteBrandById);

// models
router.get('/models', ModelController.findAll);
router.get('/models/:id', ModelController.findById);
router.get('/models/:id/brands', ModelController.findBrandByModelId);
router.post('/models', ModelController.create);
router.patch('/models/:id', ModelController.updateModelById);
router.delete('/models/:id', ModelController.deleteModelById);

// vehicles
router.get('/:plate', VehicleController.findByPlate);

export default router;
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the requiredAuthorization and requiredHeadersValidator?

Comment: Thanks, And also how you're importing them in where ever they're used, please.

and also the cars variable in the first code snippet.

Comment: added in the end of question

Comment: Thanks, I meant the file itself for cars (this one './cars'), can you share the file content?

Comment: oh sorry i miss understood, let me add it asap

Comment: I think the problem is with the imported file ``cars`` in the ``router.use('/cars', requiredAuthorization, requiredHeadersValidator, cars);``, as it's not a middleware function and doesn't return a ``next()`` call.

Comment: so u propose i change how it works the routes files and it should work?

Comment: i should have commented that if i run the tests without the authentication Middleware the tests pass

Comment: Test it without the last parameter ``cars`` as I mentioned before.

Comment: i tried that and i got the same behavior, it could be something related to how i did my tests files?

Comment: Have you tried testing your middlewares separately? Like ``router.use('/cars', requiredAuthorization); `` and ``router.use('/cars', requiredHeadersValidator)`` and see if the same behaviour persists.

Comment: Yes, after your recommendation of removing 'cars', i tried every combination, and the combination of Headers and cars work but any one with requiredAuthorization fail, so i suppose there is the faulty point

Comment: Could be... Take a look at the router.use section of the docs from express routing: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use.

Comment: Aside from that, in your ``requiredAuthorization`` file, remove the ``return;`` after the ``next()``

Comment: Okay! i will read de documentation to see some light and will remove the return, thank u for the help! i will post the resolved problem if i come to found it

Comment: i got it resolved! i will post the solution, though it was really surprising the failure point

Answer (score 0):

i got this resolved with a coworker by accident, his IDE autocompleted the file with the imports in different order, to be more precise the requiredAuthorization was the last import in the router and in the test and there the test passed without problem.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as healthcheck from 'express-healthcheck';
import requiredHeadersValidator from '../middlewares/required-headers-validator';
import cars from './cars';
import requiredAuthorization from '../middlewares/required-authorization';
```

Like this the error dissapeared (the tests were made with Jest), i suppose this could help to someone in the future to considerate the import order in case of some strange behaviour

P.D: if someone has some idea of why the order affected the behavior of this, i would be happy to know it